# NOT - EXISTS / NOT - IN type query in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have 2 data structures  like the ones below

```
(ns test)

(def l 
  [{:name "Sean" :age 27} 
   {:name "Ross" :age 27}
   {:name "Brian" :age 22}])

(def r 
  [{:owner "Sean" :item "Beer" }
   {:owner "Sean" :item "Pizza"}
   {:owner "Ross" :item "Computer"} 
   {:owner "Matt" :item "Bike"}])
```

I want to have get persons who dont own any item . (Brian in this case so [ {:name "Brian" :age 22}]
If this was SQL I would do left outer join or not exists but I not sure how to do this in clojure in more performant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Chuck's solution is certainly the most sensible one, I find it interesting that it is possible to write a solution in terms of relational algebraic operators using `clojure.set`:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])
(set/difference (set l)
                (set/project (set/join r l {:owner :name})
                             #{:name :age}))
; => #{{:name "Brian", :age 22}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You basically want to do a `filter` on `l`, but negative. We could just `not` the condition, but the `remove` function already does this for us. So something like:

```
(let [owner-names (set (map :owner r))]
  (remove #(owner-names (% :name)) l))
```

(I think it reads more nicely with the set, but if you want to avoid allocating the set, you can just do `(remove (fn [person] (some #(= (% :owner) (person :name)) r)) l)`.)

Comment: I agree it looks nicer with the set, but I would compress it to `(remove (comp (set (map :owner r)) :name) l)`

Comment: Also, allocating the set may save you a lot of time in repeated linear scans of `r`.